# Order mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I want to order my posts from mysql. Newest at first.

Whit this code working fine, but oldest posts at first place

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
```

I tried with this codes and i got an error " mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given"

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page DESC";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Im using pagination. How can i slove this?

Comment: LIMIT goes *after* ORDER BY

Comment: Any SQL tutorial should describe the order of clauses. It's not flexible.

Comment: Also debugging tip: use `error_log($sql);` to see what the SQL query looks like _after_ variables are interpolated into it. I wonder if `$offset` and `$no_of_records_per_page` are set, and are they integers?

Comment: yes


        $no_of_records_per_page = 8;
        $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

Answer (score 3):

The row-limiting syntax is `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...`.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page;
```

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries